# n+1 selector isnt working correctly when iText is processing html template

Tags: css, spring, css-selectors, itext7

In my project im converting html template with data from database to pdf. The template is processed by thymeleaf and coversion by iText addon pdfHTML.
Table with data have for example 10 rows, when data is loaded then number of rows is increasing by for example 4 rows so I want to hide those 4 rows so that the table still has 10 rows. To do this im using pseudo css selector nth-child on rows. `table tr:nth-child(n+10)`
FOR EXAMPLE - Lets say that n+10 rows will be yellow and its working when I'm checking this in html template BUT after converting its choosing 10nth row instead selecting all but the first ten.
Another strange behavior is when im changing `table tr:nth-child(n+10)` to `table tr:nth-child(-n+10)` its working perfectly which means its selecting first 10 rows from table.

U can check this on demo site from Itext https://itextpdf.com/en/demos/convert-html-css-to-pdf-free-online

Example of table to convert. https://jsfiddle.net/wxmhezbL/ Its choosing last all rows except first 3 and html is working, pdf to html not working but when u change n+3 to -n+3 its again working

Why?

Code to convert html template to pdf is from here but ive changed itext version to 4.0.2
https://springhow.com/spring-boot-pdf-generation/

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-syntax-3/#anb-microsyntax

Comment: How this link can help me?